# enzyme test component onClick action

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I would like to write test in enzyme library this line of comment. How should I write it? I really do not know how to do it.

```
<NavLink to="/payment">
    <MenuItem
        className={classes.menuItem}
        onClick={() => this.props.onMenuItemClicked()} // test this line
            selected={location.pathname === '/payment'} >
            <ListItemIcon
                className={classNames(classes.icon, {
                [classes.iconActive]: location.pathname === '/payment',
            })} >
            <SwapVertIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText
            classes={
                 location.pathname === '/payment'
                 ? { primary: classes.primaryActive }
                 : { primary: classes.primary }
             }
             inset
             primary={<FormattedMessage {...messages.paymentItem} />} 
        />
    </MenuItem>
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can spy the callback function with [SinonJS](https://sinonjs.org) and check if it has been called. You can use `sinon.spy` to listen for the callback to be triggered. And then check for it using `.called` function.

Example :

```
it('some test', () => {
   const callback = sinon.spy();
   // Mount component and do your stuff
   assert(callback.called)
})
```

If your component is already mounted, you can still set props on it so you can pass this callback as the prop and check.

Comment: Please accept the answer if this worked for you. Thanks!